# Why can't I indirectly return an object literal to satisfy an index signature return type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

These three functions seem to do the same thing, but the last one is an error. Why is this the case?

```
interface StringMap {
    [key: string]: string;
}

function a(): StringMap {
    return { a: "1" }; // OK
}

function b(): StringMap {
    var result: StringMap = { a: "1" };
    return result; // OK
}

function c(): StringMap {
    var result = { a: "1" };
    return result; // Error - result lacks index signature, why?
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## This behavior is going away.

Starting at whatever release comes after TypeScript 1.8 (or right now if you're using the bleeding-edge compiler), you will no longer see this error when the originating expression for a type is an object literal.

See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7029

---

## The Old Answer for The Old Compilers

Index signatures and object literals behave specially in TypeScript. From spec section 4.5, Object Literals:

> When an object literal is contextually typed by a type that includes a
>   string index signature of type T, the resulting type of the object
>   literal includes a string index signature with the widened form of the
>   best common type of T and the types of the properties declared in the
>   object literal.

What does this all mean?

#### Contextual Typing

Contextual typing occurs when the *context* of an expression gives a hint about what its type might be. For example, in this initialization:

```
var x: number = y;
```

The expression `y` gets a contextual type of `number` because it's initializing a value of that type. In this case, nothing special happens, but in other cases more interesting things will occur.

One of the most useful cases is functions:

```
// Error: string does not contain a function called 'ToUpper'
var x: (n: string) => void = (s) => console.log(s.ToUpper());
```

How did the compiler know that `s` was a string? If you wrote that function expression by itself, `s` would be of type `any` and there wouldn't be any error issued. But because the function was *contextually typed* by the type of `x`, the parameter `s` acquired the type `string`. Very useful!

#### Index Signatures

An *index signature* specifies the type when an object is indexed by a string or a number. Naturally, these signatures are part of type checking:

```
var x: { [n: string]: Car; };
var y: { [n: string]: Animal; };
x = y; // Error: Cars are not Animals, this is invalid
```

The lack of an index signature is also important:

```
var x: { [n: string]: Car; };
var y: { name: Car; };
x = y; // Error: y doesn't have an index signature that returns a Car
```

Hopefully it's obvious that the above two snippets ought to cause errors. Which leads us to...

#### Index Signatures and Contextual Typing

The problem with assuming that objects don't have index signatures is that you then have no way to initialize an object with an index signature:

```
var c: Car;
// Error, or not?
var x: { [n: string]: Car } = { 'mine': c };
```

The solution is that when an object literal is contextually typed by a type with an index signature, that index signature is added to the type of the object literal *if it matches*. For example:

```
var c: Car;
var a: Animal;
// OK
var x: { [n: string]: Car } = { 'mine': c };
// Not OK: Animal is not Car
var y: { [n: string]: Car } = { 'mine': a };
```

#### Putting It All Together

Let's look at the original functions in the question:

```
function a(): StringMap {
    return { a: "1" }; // OK
}
```

**OK**, because expressions in `return` statements are contextually typed by the return type of the function. The object literal `{a: "1"}` has a string value for its sole property, so the index signature can be successfully applied.

```
function b(): StringMap {
    var result: StringMap = { a: "1" };
    return result; // OK
}
```

**OK**, because the initializers of explicitly-typed variables are contextually typed by the type of the variable. As before, the index signature is added to the type of the object literal.

```
function c(): StringMap {
    var result = { a: "1" };
    return result; // Error - result lacks index signature, why?
}
```

**Not OK**, because `result`'s type does not have an index signature.

Comment: This solves my confusion about typescript indexers. Thanks for the descriptive answer.

Comment: I'm getting this error when passes an object to a function, I'm assuming it is the same issue? Any chance you can help me understand how to deal with it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668914/is-there-a-way-to-get-around-the-limitations-of-index-signatures-in-typscript