# Cannot match Request Options Header in typescript

Tags: request, typescript

I'm trying to use the Request package in Typescript, the method definition being :-

```
export function request(options?: Options, callback?: (error: any, response: any, body: any) => void): Request;
```

I have an issue trying to match the headers in the Options. The Options and Header definitions are :-

```
    export interface Options {
        url?: string;
        headers?: Headers;
        ...
        ...

    export interface Headers {
        [key: string]: any;
    }
```

My options looks like :-

```
var requestOptions = {
    url: 'https://www.wigglewoowoo.com',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Connection': 'close'
    },
    body: returnBody,
    strictSSL: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    requestCert: true,
    agent: false
};
```

I get an *"is not assignable to parameter of type Options"* unless I exclude the header. I cannot see what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best fix is to add a type annotation here (first line):

```
var requestOptions: Options = {
    url: 'https://www.wigglewoowoo.com',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Connection': 'close'
    },
    ... ...
```

To understand why, see [this long question/answer about how object literals and index signatures interact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077023/why-cant-i-indirectly-return-an-object-literal-to-satisfy-an-index-signature-re) (the case here is slightly different, but the same general problem applies).

Comment: btw... how come the compiler didn't complain about needing an index signature on the header?

Comment: One is inferred when there's a contextual type present. Without the type annotation, there's no contextual type, so no inference of an index signature occurs.