# Is there a way to get around the limitations of index signatures in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm getting the error `Index signature is missing in type`, and it is crushing my soul. I would deeply and profoundly appreciate any help understanding how to get around this. Here's the code:

```
// TestGuide.tsx
export default {
  stepOrder: ['welcome', 'basics', 'goodbye'],
  steps: {
    'welcome': <h1>Welcome to my house!</h1>,
    'basics': <h1>Maybe we should do some basics</h1>,
    'goodbye': <h1>The End.</h1>
  }
};

// guides.ts
interface Guide {
  stepOrder: string[],
  steps: {[x: string]: JSX.Element }
}

export const guideUtils = {
  getNameForStepIndex(guide: Guide, stepIndex: number): string {
    return guide.stepOrder[stepIndex];
  }
}

// TestReactComponent.tsx
import testGuide from './TestGuide';
import { guideUtils } from './guides';
guideUtils.getNameForStepIndex(testGuide, 0) 
// This is where I get the type error
// Index signature is missing in type {'welcome': ..., 'basics': ..., 'goodbye': ...}
```

How am I supposed to use types to make sure the object at `testGuide.steps` have JSX.Element values? Is there anyway to define the Guide interface, or the object in TestGuide.tsx, or anything else, that will work?

I read the following, but it didn't help me understand how to resolve the issue: [Why can't I indirectly return an object literal to satisfy an index signature return type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077023/why-cant-i-indirectly-return-an-object-literal-to-satisfy-an-index-signature-re)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. The compile doesn't know that the object you are exporting from `TestGuide.tsx` is of type `Guide`. So, you just need to tell it. One way would be:

```
import { Guide } from './guides';

export default <Guide>{
  stepOrder: ['welcome', 'basics', 'goodbye'],
  steps: {
    'welcome': "<h1>Welcome to my house!</h1>",
    'basics': "<h1>Maybe we should do some basics</h1>",
    'goodbye': "<h1>The End.</h1>"
  }
};
```

And then of course, export `Guide` from `guides.ts`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Learning/using typescript has been rather manic depressive for me. I get really excited every time it catches an error that I would have had to figure out at runtime, or maybe never caught. On the other hand, I am constantly running into stuff like this that I have no idea how to approach.

Comment: I know exactly how you feel. We switched to TypeScript a few months ago, and I felt the same way.

Comment: @Seamus _.reduce(flight.flightDetails, function(memo, seg){ return memo + seg.FlightDuration + seg.StopOverDuration; }, 0)     I am trying to send this object array to the _.reduce function. It keeps failing. How do I resolve that? I read all that was available already.

Answer (score 0):

I had to define the type of the testGuide object when I defined it. Yay for the slow and bumbling process of learning.