# Interface does not match generic Object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have an interface `foobar` with two attributes of type "number".
Now I try to match an object of type `foobar` to a generic object definition, where each attributes is of type number.

```
interface foobar {
    a: number,
    b: number
}

function baz(param: {[key: string]: number}) {
    // some math stuff here
}

const obj: foobar = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};

baz(obj); // error happens here
```

This results in the following TypeScript error.

> TS2345:Argument of type 'foobar' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: number; }'. Index signature is missing in type 'foobar'.

Is there any way I can match the object with the interface to a generic object which only has values of type number?

Comment: Worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077023/why-cant-i-indirectly-return-an-object-literal-to-satisfy-an-index-signature-re

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can match the object with the interface to a generic object which only has values of type number?

No. TypeScript doesn't know that you didn't write this:

```
// OK: This is legal code
const obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2, c: "oops" };
// OK: Structural type matches
const obj: foobar = obj1;
// Crash when baz sees c: "oops"
baz(obj); // error happens here
```

The best option in this case would be to just remove the type annotation from this line:

```
const obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};
```

Because it's a `const` initialized with an object literal, TypeScript knows there aren't any other properties lingering around on the object so it's safe(r) to use where an index signature is desired. Adding a type annotation defeats that behavior.