# TypeScript Implicit Index signatures of object types

Tags: typescript

When you define a type like `type X = { }` it will have an implicit index signature, so it can pass as a generic parameter that has an index signature whereas the same `interface` would not (it's actually the only difference in behaviour I spotted, as I continue...)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUCGAuKBnYATgJYB2A5igL4oqnAQEBmGAxtAELJpQBGO%20xclRqhIUAMIB7EgIx0APABUoEAB70SAE1xQAShBaSCm%20QNJkANFACuJANYlJAdxIA%20VwiiFrEANwjwaHp8AEZPKRlCORJgeRhXFFEgiHwAJnDpWQV2DwB6XKgAUQICIysMHTVIFnpNK1xSNigiYChNSRSoR1aACwwAN2gMEmatNTwiMhIMYGsCCBo6BmYm8S50AG1VfkJzAF0dwQp0FkPzYRQAGwhW7FhPJChKf2vW04kHp-8UDAA6VU8AHJAb4oPkiiUjCgWP8gSCwQUAPJ2KzSS4gTAjKqXIgsFrotoQRikCCaUaacYNKYzObQHgQPqDHQ4uzQaQQIA)

```
type A = {
  a: string
}

interface B {
  b: string
}

type Constraint<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = true;

type test1 = Constraint<A>
type test2 = Constraint<B> // Error, as expected, since it does not have an index signature
```

What is the implicit index signature of A though? Why does it behave differently than an explicit index signature?

```
type A = {
  a: string
}

interface C {
  [x: string]: string
  c: string
}

let a: A = { };
let c: C = { };

a.x = ''; // Error
c.x = ''; // Ok, only an explicitly defined index signature behaves like one
```

I don't understand what's the point of this implicit signature if it does not behave as one? Was it implemented as a hack to pass generic constraints like in the example above? Does it have an actual effect on type checking beyond that case?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures) the point is assignability, which shows up a lot of places in the language, such as [when you assign to variables](https://tsplay.dev/w211zW).  There are lots of cases where `X` is assignable to `Y` but you're not allowed to access them the same way directly (e.g.,  [function assignability](https://tsplay.dev/mb11EN)).  I'm not sure if that constitutes an answer, though, since "what's the point" is possibly subjective?  How should we proceed here?

Comment: The explanation in 2.0 documentation is sufficient enough. I meant, "what's the point unless it's about assignability and / or if there are any other behaviour differences" Thanks!

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Implicit index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#7029](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7029) were introduced to fix [microsoft/TypeScript#6041](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6041) and enable [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to be assigned to [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).  That is, the issue being addressed is one of *assignability*.

---

Before TypeScript 2.0, if you tried to assign an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to a variable and then tried to assign that variable to a type with an index signature, it would always fail:

```
function yell(dict: { [k: string]: string }) {
    for (const k in dict) {
        console.log(k + ": " + dict[k].toUpperCase() + "!!!")
    }
}

let x = { a: "hello", b: "goodbye" };
//  ^? let x: {a: string, b: string}

// TS 1.8 and earlier:
yell(x); // error!
//   ~ <-- {a: string, b: string} has no index signature
```

This was annoying and confusing, as described at [Why can't I indirectly return an object literal to satisfy an index signature return type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22077023/2887218).  And so we now have implicit index signatures, so that such assignments are allowed:

```
// TS 2.0 and later:
yell(x); // okay
```

Note that it is not intended that you can actually index into object literal types with any key.  It is just for assignability.

---

Do note that there was a plausible reason for the original error.  Object types in TypeScript are not sealed or exact (see [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)), meaning that a value of type `{a: string, b: string}` could have extra properties unknown to TypeScript and these could fail to match the index signature:

```
let y = { a: "hello", b: "goodbye", c: 12345 };
x = y; // allowed!
yell(x); // allowed due to implicit index signature, but runtime error!
```

So implicit index signatures are technically unsafe.  But they are just too convenient to give up, and the alternative is too inconvenient.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABATwKYBt0AoAmNoBciA3ogNoDWRAzlAE4xgDmAujfY04gL4CUJAKACQwOHURYICWogqJGiPNH7FhQqWGpx0qAHTo4TLHIDUiAERFziM0qiUWuqHACqABzeo6AYQCG1VCx+M3MAQnDzXmFuARiBHShEAA9EAF4SRF8rAAsMA3MAGkQAIysmODgcYrRrbgBuAQB6RsREAD0AfkQE5KJiLMRaBmYi0sGOZhi0TCwk3jrEZsQvOjEi-vZhplHNzm5EbP9EMDh5MBxUFOoYJjBfKBA6VCaWsgAZAHkAcTYLAYAJACib0+4VC1he5E+PysYy+Hw+ABEAEIATUBYIh8VQiWQaQyA3MuUwcEKJTKFSqNSKECIAEYAEwAZgALABWHgNFLpZALJa+EkAd1QOFCAmm2DmfJadHAsAAtqhlnRVnRIe9vr9zADgaCIoh1dCtXCESj0ZiDUsyICAEo2rWApKoCAgKAixAAKV8ADdfABlCAMNyJABivhgOhwBAhVtt9qIdgcTlcHi8fgC8moxzgiV8iFAkFgCEQQA)